# CSS - IE8 errors

Tags: css, firefox, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, compatibility

I have a wordpress website which is facing compatibility issues in Internet Explorer 8. http://www.sunsetbaycharters.net

The navigation menu is not loading properly in IE8 & IE7.

Bad Nav in IE8

[image]

Also, the content boxes in my site are not transparent in IE8. I understand that is because I'm using RGBA and I need to know how to fix it.

Please tell me how can I fix the navigation menu in IE8 & IE7 and the rgba transparent box.

CSS Code for Nav Menu:

```
div#top-menu, div#top-menu.et-fixed {
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: IE8 trouble. What else is new? :p (Also, the site is pretty.)

Comment: Please show the css code for this menu....

Comment: div#top-menu, div#top-menu.et-fixed {
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

Comment: in IE8 it's working totally fine.... but not working quit well with IE 7....

Comment: @Rony: I'm using IE8 8.0.6001.18702 and I'm facing the issues on two pcs.

Comment: try position: fixed !Important;

Comment: And buddy even i am using the same version of IE8.... Is your Browser's Document Mode is IE8 Standards????

Comment: I tried that but it didn't worked. I also tested using SauceLabs (a service for cross browser testing)

Comment: what u r getting there??

Comment: The same result as my pc.

Comment: Have u checked that you are using IE8 standards ????

Comment: I am running Document Mode: IE8 Standards.

Comment: ok... but here i am getting exactly same as chrome in IE...

Comment: You may be using Google Chrome Frame?

Comment: nop simple IE8.... with IE8 Standards...

Comment: Buddy according to this site http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/ RGBa transparency is not working in IE8. Please check

Answer (score 0):

For the content box background transparency you'll have to use a background image (as IE8 doesn't support transparency).  Just make a 5x5 square PNG of the color/transparency you'd like to use and set it as a background repeat.  For example:

```
.target-element {
    background-image: url('images/your-transparent-tile.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

As for the box spacing issue, you'll have to give us a look at your CSS.  It'll probably be something to do with IE8's lack of `display: inline-block` support.

Comment: Thanks for the method! I will try it. I have updated the main post with the css.